# How to give a form a static background picture from JPEG and place controls over it?

Tags: delphi

How to give a form a static background picture from JPEG and place controls over parts of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `TImage` on your form. Assign its `Picture` property. Put your other controls on top of it.

Answer (score 2):

This might be an easy solution for you:

- Load the JPEG at Form.OnCreate
- Set TForm.DoubleBuffered to True (in Form.OnCreate)
- In Form.OnPaint Event Handler draw/tile the picture over the form (Canvas.Draw, the TJPEGPicture should somewehere export a TGraphic which you can use for Draw()ing)
- Place TImage/TPaintBox (without images/OnPaint handlers) objects at the according locations and assign OnClick handlers

Comment: The purpose of the fourth bullet point eludes me. Why would we want a TImage without images, or a TPaintBox without an OnPaint handler?

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: You could also implement coordinate-sensitive OnMouseDown/Up events of the TForm - but with the TImage/TPaintBox you can easily move mouse-sensitive areas around on the TForm. But overlapping might cause some flickering or other graphic problems.

Comment: Or, you could just use a TButton.

Comment: @Rob i think robert assumed that the background picture contained "clickable parts". So we would use transparent controls that have a click handler (e.g. TImage/TPaintBox, but not TBevel) to get the clicks.

Comment: @Ian - exactly - TButtons are usually opaque and I assumed the clickable parts should be transparent.

Comment: @Robert i think Rob assumed that the background picture was static watermark, while the form still has its regular complement of interactive controls.  :D